Is it possible to randomly generate objects along a selected objects edge or curve?
Looking to see if I can add objects along another objects edge (or a curve) from a selection of objects (E.G: Cube, Sphere, Cone).  What I'm also looking for is the ability to edit the objects that have been generated afterwards.
Below is an example of what I want to achieve but on a larger scale :

The 3 smaller objects would be randomly generated fully around the selected edge loop in no particular order.
Pretty sure Geometry Nodes will play a part in this but I'm fairly new to it and can't see an edge option.
Any help is appreciated!

With geometry nodes there are a few options:

For all of them, you will need a collection containing the random things.

The "origin" of the random things must be at their center or base depending on your goal (the point that will coincide with the geometry is the origin)
The scale of the random things must be 1 (apply scale if needed with ctrl+a)


Option 1:
On existing vertices of geometry:

Option 2
Random points on faces:

Option 3
On curves:

Important:
Since you want to "edit" the random things later:

you need the "realize instances" node (to transform instances into actual geometry
you need to "apply" the geometry nodes (to make the modifier become an actual mesh)



For using the "selected loop"

Make a "tool" geometry nodes instead of a "modifier"



Make it available in "edit" mode


Then you use a "Selection" node to read the selected points. In this case, I used a "capture attribute" instead of using two "sample index"

Alternatively, you can convert the selected loop to curve (mesh to curve) and use the curve option instead.

File


This works really well!  Slight improvement which I forgot to mention.  Is it possible to make the generations equal distance apart and in order?  Kind of like an array modifier but with the randomness of each object?

On a curve, yes. (Convert mesh to curve with "mesh to curve"). On the "sample curve" node, the "factor" will be (instead of a "random value") an expression "index" / point count - @Gracus

If the post answers your question, please mark it as answered
